# Materializ.min.css link is not working on staging server

Tags: angular, materialize

[image]On localhost, everything is working fine. But as I pushed my code to the staging server some of the styling was effected. I checked various links i-e; bootstrap, font awesome, materialize, all of them are there except materialize.min.css. I don't know, what's the reason. In the image provided last link gets disappeared on staging server.

Comment: How did you refered that file in your code?

Comment: On index file there I just pasted the link and nothing else

Comment: Whenever I manually put that link using inspect window then works fine